# Search operator inquestion:this broken

Tags: bug, search

I'm following these directions:

> If you are searching using the search box on a question page, you can use `inquestion:this` to restrict results to the post you are already viewing.
>   <sub>[Advanced Search Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)</sub>

I have done this in the past and it has worked. However, right now it is not working and I am not getting the results for the question I am searching from. It's not working on any site I've tried. It appears to ignore the operator entirely, like the operator is invalid ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3Apotato) is an invalid search for comparison).

Comment: I read that as Inquisition. I did not expect this. I do wonder if its related to search improvements

Comment: @JourneymanGeek No one ever expects the Spanish Inquisition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere along the line, it started to work again:

> [image]